# Can a transient suffix have a value like an infix?

Tags: transient-library

I'm writing a [transient](https://github.com/magit/transient) for invoking [debchange](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/devscripts/debchange.1.en.html). It has a number of regular options like `--multimaint` which I am adding infixes for, and then a handful of mutually exclusive options like `--append` of which one must be specified. I would like to make these suffixes without defining a whole pile of wrappers like `(debchange-append)`; can I somehow give the suffix a value so that I can use the same `(debchange-run)` command for all of them?

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
(defclass dd-suffix-switch (transient-suffix)
  ((argument :initarg :argument)))

(cl-defmethod transient-infix-value ((obj dd-suffix-switch))
  (oref obj argument))
```

which I can then use as:

```
("a" "Append" dd-dch :class dd-suffix-switch :argument "--append")
```

EDIT: Whoops, this doesn't work after all, I get *all* of my suffixes.